# Find the maximum number of pieces of a cake in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion, while-loop

What is the maximum number of pieces which a hypercake (a disc generalized to ≥2 dimensions) can be cut into using -many hyperplanar (−1-dimensional) cuts? The answer is (0)+(1)+(2)+(3)+⋯+() pieces.

(k)=!k!(−k)! when 0≤k≤

```
def hypercake(n, k):
    def combinations(n, r):
        def factorial(n):
            if n <= 1:
                return 1
            else:
                return (n * factorial(n - 1))
        if 0 <= r and r <= n:
            return factorial(n)/(factorial(r) * factorial(n-r))
        else:
            return 0
    if k >= 2:
        while k >= 2:
            total = 0
            total = total + combinations(n, k)
            k -= 1
            return total

print(hypercake(6, 5))
```

I have written the subprograms for combinations (nk) and for factorials, But I'm confused on how I should add the number of combinations to get my answer. When I call hypercake(6, 5) im supposed to get 63 but when I run my program I get 6.

Comment: Does this help if k >= 2: should be inside if\else condition block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things wrong with your answer.

Firstly, you are resetting `total` to 0 in your while loop.
Secondly, you are returning `total` in your while loop.

This means you are essentially only getting the first result of `k=5` assuming `n=6, k=5`.

Thirdly, you are cutting the results of with `while k >= 2`, discounting `k=1` and `k=0`. These 2 values should still be considered for your results.

```
def hypercake(n,k):
    def combinations(n, r):

        def factorial(n):
            if n <= 1:
                return 1
            else:
                return (n * factorial(n - 1))

        if 0 <= r and r <= n:

            return factorial(n)/(factorial(r) * factorial(n-r))
        else:

            return 0
        
    if k >= 2:
        
        total = 0
        while k >= 0:
            
            total = total + combinations(n, k)
            k -= 1
        return total
        
print(hypercake(6,5))
```

More importantly, this seems like a homework assignment and it's likely that one of the main goals/test requirements is considering how much time this function will take. At each run, you are essentially re-calculating the factorials of values repeatedly. Think about how you can reduce the amount of calculations performed.